# XAML Setting Point for child elements in Grid

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a Grid with some child Image elements in it.  the user is able to drag and drop these (constrained within the parent bounds).  I can get their location as a Point by the following code;

```
var transform = ele.TransformToVisual(ContentPanel);
Point absolutePosition = transform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

Getting the Point cor-ords like this works great.  However I would like to **set** the Point when the user navigates to this page.  Is it possible to do this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can use margin property to set the position of image in Grid Control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var transform = ele.TransformToVisual(ContentPanel);
Point absolutePosition = transform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

Do some code to decide where to move it and then:

```
double x = 456;
double y = 345;
double finalx = absolutePosition.X - x;
double finaly = absolutePosition.Y - y;
ele.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform() {X = finalx,Y = finaly };
```